# Gitlab Kubernetes executor runner execution job logs not visible

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I configured Gitlab runner (version 11.4.2) to use Kubernetes executor.

Here is my non-interactive registrer command:

```
gitlab-runner register
  --non-interactive \
  --registration-token **** \
  --url https://mygitlab.net/ \
  --tls-ca-file /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/ca.crt \
  --executor "kubernetes" \
  --kubernetes-image-pull-secrets pull-internal \
  --kubernetes-image-pull-secrets pull-external \
  --name "kube-docker-runner" \
  --tag-list "docker" \
  --config "/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml" \
  --kubernetes-image "docker:latest" \
  --kubernetes-helper-image "gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-latest" \
  --output-limit 32768
```

It works fine and I can see the execution log in the Gitlab UI

[image: start_job]
[image: success_jobs]

In kubernetes, I see the runner pod composed by 2 containers : helper and build. I expected to see execution job logs by watching the build container logs but it's not the case. I would like to centralize these job execution log with a tool like fluentdbit by reading the container stdout output.

If I start the docker:latest alone (without runner execution) in a pod deployed in the same kubernetes cluster, I can see the logs on stdout. Any idea for configuring the stdout of build container properly ?